# How do you paste from one sheet to another with an offset?

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I'm trying to modify a report to allow for removing duplicate part numbers before continuing with other calculations related to the part numbers.

To do this, I figured the easiest way to ensure the data didn't get corrupted in the final sheet would be to create a separate sheet, copy the initial data, remove duplicates, then copy and paste that column into the final sheet that already has its headers and looks pretty.

I am trying to paste with an offset so we can keep the headers in place and not have to manually code them in.

I've tried:

```
PNView.Columns(1,1).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial
PNView.Cells(1,1).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial
PNView.Range("A2").PasteSpecial
```

It gives me a run-time error every time. It either gives me a 438, or it tells me you can't paste here because it's not the same size.

This is my latest iteration:

```
CMT.Range("$G5:$G3500").Copy
ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
Range("A:A").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AM" & Cells(Rows.Count, 
"a").End(xlUp).Row).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:= _
    xlYes

PNView.Range("A2").Resize(ws.Range("A:A").Rows.Count, 
ws.Range("A:A").Columns.Count).Value = ws.Range("A:A")
```

I need to ultimately be able to transfer the data in ws.Range("A:A") to PNView.Range starting at A2.

Resolution:

So we took a shortcut and recorded a macro to do exactly what we wanted it to do, and  this is the result Excel gave that works:

```
CMT.Select
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.Copy
ws.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks 
_
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Rows("1:3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Columns("A:A").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Copy
PNView.Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks 
_
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to paste the maximum number of rows into a space the max number of rows less 1. Try just using the used range by finding the last used row.

Comment: SJR, the place I'm trying to paste is empty. Are you saying to do a count of the rows in the copy and then paste to those specific rows in the final sheet?

Comment: Yes. The problem is that in this line you can't resize the max number of rows starting at A2 as you are off the sheet. `PNView.Range("A2").Resize(ws.Range("A:A").Rows.Count`.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:

So we took a shortcut and recorded a macro to do exactly what we wanted it to do, and this is the result Excel gave that works, with edits to include the variables we are using:

```
CMT.Select
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.Copy
ws.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks 
_
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Rows("1:3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Columns("A:A").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Copy
PNView.Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks 
_
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```